# Arduino: XBee mesh network

Tags: arduino, xbee, zigbee, mesh-network

I'm a newbie with XBeeS2 module. I have several XBee "router" and 1 XBee "coordinator" on my home area network.

A couple of questions:

- Can I change from my application (Arduino) the XBee address? Or each XBee address must be configured before with the X-CTU tool (or another one)?
- From my XBee "router", how can I retrieve the XBee "coordinator" address from my application (Arduino)?

Answer (score 2):

- **For your first Q:**
   No you can't change the address even in your X-CTU Software, we use X-CTU to let the device know "with which
  other device it can communicate".
- **For second one :**
   You have to attach the router(Serial TX,RX) with an Arduino(Serial RX,TX) and configure the router in API mode,
  then you can make an **API format for AT Command**, to request the
  value of (SL-Serial Number Low) which is the 4bytes LSB of the
  coordinator address.

I prefer to let the coordinator work with the Arduino, and let the
   router do your work,because any router can communicate with its PAN
   coordinator, but coordinator frames in some applications needs to
   communicate with a specific router.

For more information about the API frames and a lot of thins in XBee you can download the *[XBee/XBee-PRO RF Modules-DIGI international](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kc2gvys6ods8c9d/XBee-Datasheet.pdf)* or *[Building Wireless Sensor Network](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596807732)* .
**Greetings ....**

Answer (score 2):

Physical address (64bits) and network address (16 bits) are READ-ONLY.

You can send data to coordinator using the physical address as

```
0x0000000000000000 (64 bits)
```

and use

```
0xFFFE (16 bits)
```

for the network address if the address is unknown.

But if you want to retrieve the exactly address, you need to use the Remote AT Commando (API mode) and query the SL(Serial Number Low) and SH (Serial Number High) commands.